# Error 500.19 The configuration section 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, iis

I'm new to IIS, I'm trying to mount a web application on the IIS of the server, but at the moment of running it shows me a message "The configuration section 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration", when I mount it on my computer if it works but when I pass it to the server it sends me the message , my application is made in asp mvc and I connect to the Oracle database 11g

[image]

```html
 100:   </system.data>
  101:   <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  102:     <version number="*">
```

this is my webconfig

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación ASP.NET, visite
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />-->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <!--<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" ></error>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Error" ></error>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>-->
  <!--<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>-->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    -->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ProductoModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ProductoModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ProductoModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe;PASSWORD=andres;USER ID=ANDRES&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MonterreyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbConnMonterrey.dbMonterreyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.dbConnMonterrey.dbMonterreyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbConnMonterrey.dbMonterreyModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myserver;PASSWORD=*******;USER ID=*******&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MonterreyProdEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbMonterreyProduccion.dbMonterreyProdModel.csdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyProduccion.dbMonterreyProdModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyProduccion.dbMonterreyProdModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myserver;PASSWORD=*****;USER ID=*****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MonterreyAndresEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbMonterreyAndres.dbMonterreyAndresModel.csdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyAndres.dbMonterreyAndresModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyAndres.dbMonterreyAndresModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myserver;PASSWORD=*****;USER ID=*****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="dbMonterreyREPREGEREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbMonterreyProduccion.dbMonterreyREPREGERProduccion.csdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyProduccion.dbMonterreyREPREGERProduccion.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyProduccion.dbMonterreyREPREGERProduccion.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myserver;PASSWORD=*****;USER ID=*****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MonterreyPreProduccionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbMonterreyPreProduccion.dbMonterreyPreProduccionModel.csdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyPreProduccion.dbMonterreyPreProduccionModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyPreProduccion.dbMonterreyPreProduccionModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myserver;PASSWORD=******;USER ID=******&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MonterreyREPREGERPreProduccionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbMonterreyPreProduccion.dbMonterreyREPREGERPreProduccionModel.csdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyPreProduccion.dbMonterreyREPREGERPreProduccionModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbMonterreyPreProduccion.dbMonterreyREPREGERPreProduccionModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myserver;PASSWORD=*****;USER ID=******&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 16):

To use `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` element in web.config, it is necessary to register it with `<section>` or `<sectionGroup>` element inside `<configSections>`. You should uncomment this part because in your example it still commented:

```
<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" 
         type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

If uncommenting that line still not working, change it to `<sectionGroup>` element:

```
<sectionGroup name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" 
              type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

Also make sure that ODP Managed Data Access is already registered as assembly reference in your project and/or GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing your `web.config` file manually you can also use application `OraProvCfg.exe`. Execute script like below (pick the version which is installed on your system):

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net
set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net
set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe
set OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

set TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\network\admin
set CONFIGFILE_PATH=.../web.config


REM Delete configuration, if needed
"OraProvCfg_x64" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /configfile:%$CONFIGFILE_PATH%
"OraProvCfg_x86" /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /configfile:%$CONFIGFILE_PATH%



REM Add configuration
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:config /configfile:%$CONFIGFILE_PATH% /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:config /configfile:%$CONFIGFILE_PATH% /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
```

If you skip `/configfile:...` then the application modifies the global `machine.config` file. Perhaps you also have to configure `/product:aspnet`, run `OraProvCfg.exe` and check the printout.

```
Oracle Providers for .NET Configuration Utility for .NET Framework 4 : Release 4.122.1.0 Production on Do Okt 18 09:00:41 2018
Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Usage:

OraProvCfg  /action:<action>
            [/force]
            [/configfile:<app/web.config file path]
            [/product:<product>]
            [/component:<component name>]
            [/productversion:<product version>]
            [/frameworkversion:<.NET version>]
            [/providerpath:<provider path>]
            [/verbose:<verbose>]
            [/log:<log file path>]
            [/set:[*\]<section name>\<attribute name>:<attribute value>]
            [/unset:[*\]<section name>\<attribute name>:<attribute value>]

            <action>          = gac | ungac | register | unregister |
                                config | unconfig

            <configfile>      = complete file path of app/web.config
                                for configuring/ unconfiguring odp/odpm/ASP.net entries only.
            <product>         = odp | odpm | aspnet

            <component name>  = oraclepermission | perfcounter |
                                dbproviderfactory

                                (for odp or odpm only)

                              = all (default) | membership | profile | sitemap
                                | rolemanager | personalization | webevent |
                                a combination (i.e. "membership|profile")
                                (for aspnet only)

            <product version> = 4 digit assembly version number of the product
                                (i.e. 4.112.2.0)

            <.NET version>    = .NET Framework version
                                (i.e. v2.0.50727 or v4.0.30319)

            <provider path>   = full path location of the .NET assembly,
                                including the the assembly file name
                                (i.e. c:\OH\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll)

            <verbose>         = true (default) | false

            <log file name>   = full path of the log file to log output

            <section name>    = subsection name of oracle.manageddataaccess
                                .client
                                (e.g.)distributedTransaction

            <attribute name>  = attribute name
                                (e.g.)oramts_sess_txntimetolive

            <attribute value> = attribute value (e.g.)240
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to manage the connection strings myself, instead of accepting Oracle's edit of the web.config file.

Comment out the `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` and corresponding `<configSections>` entry that oracle inserts.

Instead, I use the Microsoft `<connectionStrings>` section that can be accessed by the ConfigurationManager

`<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DB_CONN_STRING" connectionString="Data Source=servername:1521/dbinstancename;User ID=user;Password=pwd;"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Then in code, create my connection with:

```
using System.Configuration;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_CONN_STRING"].ConnectionString;

OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(conString);
myConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably disabled the <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client".../> in your web.config because you were getting errors about it being a duplicate declaration.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. Not everyone has the luxury or desire to modify the machine.config (especially on a server). Perhaps the easiest way to solve this problem is to use bindingRedirect in your web.config (or app.config, if not a web application) to resolve the version conflicts between your web application and what is listed in the the machine.config..

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.122.21.1" newVersion="4.122.21.1"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**NOTE:** The version I am using is `4.122.21.1`. Be sure you match your own version that you are using.

**NOTE:** The redirect is on `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, not `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`; this is a common mistake that developers make.

If you want to make the change in the machine.config, proceed carefully as this could have unanticipated consequences on other apps on the machine. The simplest modification is to change the version of the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client section from a strong version to any version by using an asterisk "*".

```
<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=*, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

If you need additional clarification, let me know and I can give more details.